# Scripting a Batch File that looks for a SUCCESS Message

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Windows Batch File:

I have a log that is created by a process. Now I want to create a batch file that checks this log file for a specific success message:

```
 BDX 2013/07/25 23:08:02 -I- DATABASE SUCCESSFULL
```

Now there are several of these success entries at different timestamps in the log file, since the log file just adds the latest success messages.

So I want to check the log file for the LATEST success message, and compare it to the date stamp on the log file (date value of the log file, meaning the last time it was written to)**:** If the date of the **latest success entry** in the log file **matches** the log file's date stamp, it should run another batch file (eg. call another.bat). If it does not match, meaning the last success entry is older than the timestamp on the log file, it should just write an error log (error.log) containing the words: 'DATABASE UNSUCCESSFUL' with the current timestamp next to it...

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: What is the date format in your DIR listing?   Does this have to work across multiple machines with different regional settings, or just the one machine?

Comment: Yeah, just one machine...Date format is: YY-MM-DD hh:mm AM/PM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('findstr /i /c:"DATABASE SUCCESSFULL" logfile.txt') do set "success=%%a"
for %%a in (logfile.txt) do set "filedate=%%~ta"
if "%filedate:~0,10%"=="%success%" (
    call another.bat
) else (
    >>otherlogfile.log echo(%date% %time% DATABASE UNSUCCESSFUL
)
```

Comment: We have very similar code, though I was writing mine without knowing you had posted already.

Comment: thank you very much! Your code works. You just have a syntax error in it - ...echo(%... The ( bracket

Comment: @DextrousDave the bracket after `echo` is right, it works better than `echo.` to avoid the message `echo is off.`.

Comment: OK thanks. there is a problem with your script. I played around with it a bit, and when I change the string from DATABASE SUCCESSFUL to DATABASE UNSUCCESSFUL with the same date value to it, it still runs the other.bat file...and it is not suppose to... Basically, it does not explicitly look for the string "DATABASE SUCCESSFUL", but instead only for "DATABASE"...So even if I add "DATABASE BLABLA", it gets a positive match

Comment: @DextrousDave I changed the Regex, please try it now.

Comment: One more thing. I migrated the use for this Batch file from a Windows 7 machine to a windows server 2008 machine, and the timeformat on that machine is  YY-MM-DD hh:mm, and not  YY/MM/DD hh:mm, how would the code change then? Since it keeps giving me false matches(that is writing the error log file) everytime on the Windows server machine. Thanks

Comment: Another thing - I see that on the windows server that the date-format in the log file differs from that of the server date format - yyy/mm/dd vs yyyy-mm-dd. Should this create any problems? Like I said, script works fine on my Win 7 PC with date format yyy/mm/dd...